# How to delete or hide appBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem; I need to hide or remove the appBar in my app. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB6ct.png)  I've read a bunch of articles, but I can't find the answer. If I just delete or set the appBar to null, then my widget will be slick at the top.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR37K.png)

---

Here's my code in Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/widgets/balance.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/widgets/chart.dart';

import './widgets/new_transaction.dart';
import './widgets/transaction_list.dart';
import './models/transaction.dart';
import './widgets/balance.dart';
import 'widgets/outcome.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Expenses',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // String titleInput;
  // String amountInput;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    // Transaction(
    //   id: 't1',
    //   title: 'New Shoes',
    //   amount: 69.99,
    //   date: DateTime.now(),
    // ),
    // Transaction(
    //   id: 't2',
    //   title: 'Weekly Groceries',
    //   amount: 16.53,
    //   date: DateTime.now(),
    // ),
  ];

  List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
    return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
      return tx.date.isAfter(
        DateTime.now().subtract(
          Duration(days: 7),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  void _addNewTransaction(
      String txTitle, double txAmount, DateTime chosenDate) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: chosenDate,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteTransaction(String id) {
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.removeWhere((tx) {
        return tx.id == id;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Chart(_recentTransactions),
            TransactionList(_userTransactions, _deleteTransaction),
            Card(
              elevation: 10,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
              child: Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: TextButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () => startAddNewTransaction(context),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_task_outlined),
                  label: Text(
                    'Add expenses',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TotalBalance(),
            TotalOutcome()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to hide the appBar to continue working on the design and code.

Comment: just wrap your scaffold in SafeArea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way will be wrapping your body with SafeArea, as setting AppBar to transparent will still take up unnecessary space, it would be better to use padding for it.

Something like this:

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have created an appbar in your code.
 remove the title of your appBar,
set `elevation` to `0`  and `background color` to `transparent`:

```
AppBar(
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
     )
```

Comment: But I want to use that space, the appBar is still there, I want to use that space for my widgets.

Comment: then remove the appbar and using padding

Comment: wrap your `Column ` widget with `Padding` and give it few pixels padding so widgets won't  slick at top

Comment: @Saad It's better not to use Padding only after removing AppBar as the result might differ for different devices, it's better to use SafeArea for consistency across different devices.

Comment: Thanks for your information, didn't knew about it